# Can application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk make a call to on-premises DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We plan to run a java application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and it would want make a call to an on-premises database via Hibernate or jdbc.

Is this allowed or do we face any issues ?

How secure would be this connection provided we have a direct connect setup and dedicated VPC, private and public subnets. Is there a way to say that have the EC2 in the BeanStalk running in private subnet connect to the DB or does that happen automatically?

Answer (score 0):

> want make a call to an on-premises database..  Is this allowed or do we face any issues ?..

Until you can provide connection to the on-premise database with reasonable latency and availability,  the only issue is securing the connection. I'd say VPN is mandatory in this case.

> How secure would be this connection provided we have a direct connect setup and dedicated VPC

You don't really need aws direct connect (dedicated connection is to ensure latency and throughout), if you have it, good for you :) Setting up VPN is indeed best practice for connecting to the on-premise systems.

Personally I don't like the idea accessing an on-premise database directly (without proxy/api in DMZ), however it is my own personal preference.

VPN can be seen as extending your own infrastructure, when you setup routing, VPN and firewall correctly, your app should be able to connect to the DB seamlessly